# Setting a data breakpoint in Visual Studio 2005 on the address of a dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I wonder if there's a way to do the following: I have a structure containing a member which is a pointer to a block of memory allocated by the kernel when I pass the structure to an API function (the structure is a WAVEHDR, the member is the *reserved* field.)

I can set a data breakpoint on the value of the reserved member - that in itself is not very helpful. What I'd like to do, when the breakpoint is hit, is to dereference the pointer stored in *reserved* and set a new data breakpoint on the memory pointed to by that pointer. I would like VisualStudio to break when that memory is set to a known value.

I know how to set a breakpoint from a macro, and how to have Visual Studio invoke that macro from a breakpoint when it's hit, but I don't know whether I can pass the pointer value to the macro so that it can set the breakpoint on the right address. The UI doesn't provide a way to do it.

Is there a way for the macro to access information about the running program, and do things like evaluate global variables or other expressions? I could accomplish what I'm trying to do if I had that kind of programmatic access to the running code (during a breakpoint) from the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macro can evaluate anything that you can in the watch window:

```
    Dim e As EnvDTE.Expression

    e = DTE.Debugger.GetExpression("<my expression>", True)

    If e.IsValidValue Then
        ... use e.Value to do something
    End If
```

The value you get back in e.Value is exactly the string you would see in the watch window, so you may have to pull it apart.  There are also a bunch of other properties on the Expression object you can use. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.expression(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if thats possible. I know that there are conditional breakpoints, but that would require knowing the memory address ahead of time...

Something along the lines of *p == 0xADDRESS in the conditional break dialog.